# How to prevent firefox to be opened after exporting document with polymode markdown in R?

Tags: r, emacs, r-markdown

I use Emacs ESS as my environment for programming in R

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 (x86_46)
Emacs version: 27.1
```

And I have the following as polymode configuration in my init file (I installed from MELPA three packages: polymode, poly-markdown and poly-r)

```
; ==========================
; Polymode for R markdown
; ==========================
; M-x package-install [RET] polymode [RET]
; M-x package-install [RET] poly-markdown [RET]
; M-x package-install [RET] poly-R [RET]
;
(use-package polymode
       :diminish (poly-org-mode
              poly-markdown-mode
              poly-noweb+r-mode
              poly-noweb+r-mode
              poly-markdown+r-mode
              poly-rapport-mode
              poly-html+r-mode
              poly-brew+r-mode
              poly-r+c++-mode
              poly-c++r-mode)
       :init
       (require 'poly-R)
       (require 'poly-markdown)
       :config
       (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.md$" . poly-markdown-mode))
       (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rmd$" . poly-markdown+r-mode))
       (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rcpp$" . poly-r+c++-mode))
       (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.cppR$" . poly-c++r-mode))
       )
```

This works. I press `M-n e`, this runs and produces a html document and at the end the program opens Firefox browser with the content of the generated html file. What I would like to do is to generate only the html document but without opening the browser. As a matter of fact I view the generated html page inside emacs via eww and I reload the page after each html export by pressing `g`.

When I create a markdown I split the current Emacs window into three buffers described as below:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+   Here is the buffer      +                            +
+   in which I write        +   This eww buffer acts as  +
+   my markdown file with   +   my web browser and       +
+   my R programs.          +   shows the content of     +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   the generated HTML file  +
+   Here is the buffer for  +   as if I was viewing it   +
+   R to run the program    +   via Google Chrome,       +
+   and generate the HTML   +   Firefox etc.             +
+   file with all messages. +                            +
+                           +   Each time there is a new +
+                           +   version of the HTML      +
+                           +   document I come back to  +
+                           +   this buffer and after    +
+                           +   pressing 'g' I reload    +                           
+                           +   the page.                +
+                           +                            +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Working this way in Emacs seems to me convenient. As a result, there is no reason to have a Firefox window opening after each new version of the generated file, it's annoying and each time I have to close it manually.

So my question is: Is there any command that only runs the program and generates the HTML file but without opening it with Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to your problem in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58573524/7204113

```
(setq polymode-display-output-file nil)
```